# Dataframe results to bigquery are empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am working in a google cloud function with the intention of putting the results in a dataframe and then porting all of that into BigQuery. My function was able to be deployed without error but when looking into the associated bq table I am seeing no data. Below is a view of my code:

```
# general setup, common imports
import json, requests, time, urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
import io
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

def crux_data():
    # Read the URLs for auditing
    url_list = open('pagespeedlist', 'r')
    url_list.read()

    results = []

    for x in url_list:
        url = x[0]
        pagespeed_results = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={}&strategy=mobile&key=API_KEY'\
            .format(url)).read().decode('UTF-8')
        pagespeed_results_json = json.loads(pagespeed_results)
        add_date = datetime.date.today()
        largest_contentful_paint = pagespeed_results_json['lighthouseResult']['audits']['largest-contentful-paint']['displayValue'].replace(u'\xa0', u'') # Largest Contenful Paint
        first_input_delay = str(round(pagespeed_results_json['loadingExperience']['metrics']['FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS']['distributions'][2]['proportion'] * 1000, 1)) + 'ms' # First Input Delay
        cumulative_layout_shift = pagespeed_results_json['lighthouseResult']['audits']['cumulative-layout-shift']['displayValue'] # CLS
        crux_lcp = pagespeed_results_json['loadingExperience']['metrics']['LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS']['category'] # Largest Contenful Paint Score
        crux_fid = pagespeed_results_json['loadingExperience']['metrics']['FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS']['category'] # First Input Delay Score
        crux_cls = pagespeed_results_json['loadingExperience']['metrics']['CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE']['category'] # CLS Score
        result_url = [url,date,largest_contentful_paint,first_input_delay,cumulative_layout_shift,lcp_score,fid_score,cls_score]
        results.append(result_url)

    #Convert to dataframe
    results_csv = DataFrame (results,columns=['URL','DATE','LCP','FID','CLS','LCP_SCORE','FID_SCORE','CLS_SCORE'])

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'credentials.json'
    client = Client()

    # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    table_id = "db.datatable.dataLoc"

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        results_csv, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

    table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print(
        "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
            table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
         )
    )
```

I do see the proper schema in the bq table but no actual data. Is there something I am missing with loading a df to bigquery?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but I think your code could be much cleaner using [`pd.read_gbq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html)